# Global Variable For Site Domain

Tags: ee2

Is there any way - in Expression Engine - that there is a global variable or even a constant to reference the domain of the current site you are working on instead of hard coding the domain name in your links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [global variable {site_url}](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#site-url)

But if you code your links as "/path/to/a/page" (with the initial slash) then that will work just the same.